# Need help ordering numbers in Python(Ascending Order)

Tags: python-3.x

I'm fairly new to coding and just started this week. I'm attempting to order numbers such as test grades in ascending order. I've tried it and here's what I have (below) - it doesn't sort the list. What am I missing? I'm using Pyscripter to code python.

```
li=['75, 95, 65, 100, 10']

li.sort()

print(li)
```

Comment: Hint: you have a list of length 1 and type string.  Try li=[75.95,65,100,10] instead

Comment: Thanks that worked. I guess i didn't need the apostrophes in my code. After removing parentheses this is what i have                                                                                                 li=[75, 95, 65, 100, 10]
li.sort()
print(li)

Answer (score 0):

`li=['75,95,65,100,10']` reads one string only.

Either use

`li=['75','95','65','100','10']` (list of strings)

or `li=[75,95,65,100,10]` (list of ints). That should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
li=[75, 95, 65, 100, 10]
for i in range(len(li)):
    for x in range (i+1, len(li)):
        if li[i] > li[x]:
            li[x], li[i] = li[i], li[x]
print(li)
```

I modified the list by removing the `' '` inside the `li=[]` because you have int numbers and not strings, if you want to understand much easy Python I recommend to start with the basic loops and not with predefined functions like `sort()`.

Answer (score -1):

`li=[75, 95, 65, 100, 10]`

`li.sort(key=int)`# ascending order.

For descending order add:

`li.sort(key=int, reverse=True )`

`print (li)`

Comment: the key function is unneeded in this case